# Reference to dynamically created Buttons

Tags: android, android-button

I have been looking for how to create Buttons dynamically. Finally, I got it.
However, I don’t know yet how to make a reference to a specific created Button.
For instance, in my example below, how could I put the text of a specific Button in red when clicked?

That is, how to put its id:

```
Button button_pulsado = (Button) findViewById(R.id.???????);
Button.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

This is my example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
      myList.add("A");
      myList.add("B");
      myList.add("C");
      myList.add("D");

      for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText(myList.get(i));

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new       LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the cure that changes the text color? What class and method?

Comment: And which view do you want to change? The button that was clicked? Or another view?

Comment: I want to change the clicked Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around the `findViewById` issue, you could store a `List<Button>`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

Add to that while you build your dynamic view.

```
ll.addView(myButton, lp);
buttons.add(myButton);
```

Use `buttons.get(int position)` instead of `findViewById`.

---

Regarding...

> For instance, in my example below, how could I put the text of a specific Button in red when clicked?

You can set the color within a separate click listener for each button as you add them into the View.

```
class ColorClickListener implements View.onClickListener {
    private String color;
    ColorClickListener(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // v.setBackground(color); // For example... API may not like this
    }
}
```

And from the Activity

```
String [] colors = new String[] {"#fff", "#ccc"}; 

for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setOnClickListener(new ColorClickListener(Color.parseColor(colors[i])));
}
```

Comment: I don't know how the complete line of "buttons.get(int position)" would be, could you help me please?

Comment: And I don't know how you want to use the buttons. It's just an ArrayList. It has a get method. You call it with the position of the button you want. Really simple

Comment: Could it be like this?:

Comment: Button button1 = (Button) buttons.get(1)(R.id.buttons[1]);

Comment: @FAR No. `R.id.buttons` is not an array. Also, two sets of parentheses in a row is invalid syntax and a compiler error.

Comment: `buttons.get` returns a Button already. You cannot index a Button @FAR

Comment: @FAR I don't think the `List<Button>` is necessary. As this answer shows and mine states more explicitly, you can use the `View` parameter in `onClick()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call `findViewById()`. The `onClickMethod()` has a `View` argument which references the view which was clicked:

```
private changeColorClick = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        buttons.add(myButton);
        v.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

}
```

Now inside of your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setTextColor(myList.get(i));
    myButton.setOnClickListener(changeColorClick);
}
```

If you want each button to change to a different color, you can either create the `OnClickListener` as a named class with a constructor:

```
public ColorClick implements OnClickListener() {
    private Color color;
    public ColorClick(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Now you will need an array, `List`, or `Map` of `Color` objects to use during construction of the `OnClickListener`. For example,

```
Color[] colors = new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE};
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setTextColor(myList.get(i));
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new ColorClick(colors[i]);
}
```

Or you can use `setTag()` on the buttons.

Comment: @cricket_007 My bad =p

Comment: Thanks very much. Your suggestions have helped me to solve my problems. However, now another one has appeared: I don’t know how to return the text of the Button to the original color (black) when another Button is clicked. I would be grateful if someone helps me.

Comment: @FAR For future reference, you should just post a new question. Also be sure to accept an answer after the delay timer is up.